# EXCEL VBA to add blank rows to make them them a set of number

Tags: vba, excel

hi i need to add blank rows to 3 set od data to make them 92 each.

For example i have a data from A1:A85, A86:A167, A168:A248 but i wan to make them to 92 each a set by adding remaining blank rows. can any has any VBA for this. (First set 85 data points want to add 7 blank rows to make 92, 
second set 82 data points wan to ad 10 blank rows like wise)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little difficult to understand, but I think I know what you are trying to ask. For any Range object less than 92 rows, I think you want to add additional blank rows, essentially "padding" the current region, so that it is exactly 92 rows long. You don't seem to care about columns.  You can add additional rows to a Range object using it's `.Resize` property. As you say, `Range("A1:A85")` has only 85 rows. Somewhere inside your procedure, you could use something like

```
Set MyRange = Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'Work with one specific data set
Set MyRange = MyRange.Resize(92-MyRange.Rows.Count, 0) 'Add rows so that count adds to 92
                                                       'but zero columns
```

You can view the Help Page on the [Range.Resize property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193274(v=office.15).aspx) for more information. A `Select...Case` routine could then help you add rows to other data sets in your Worksheet. Unfortunately, without seeing your code no one can test this to verify.